# Java - How to change components height using BoxLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

So, I have a tiny GUI program and I decided to use the BoxLayout to display the components from top to bottom. Everything works fine but I'm not able to change the height of my JButtons. I tried many things like **setPreferredSize()** but then i had the problem that the width isn't correct, as well. Using **setMaximumSize()** sets the width like i want to but the height still doensn't change. Maybe some of you could help me :) Thanks

```
public class SimpleSkinViewer extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private final Dimension boxDimension = new Dimension(320, 320);
    private final Dimension buttonDimension = new Dimension(320, 60);
    private final Dimension spaceDimension = new Dimension(0, 5);

    private JLabel imagebox;
    private JButton loadButton;
    private JButton changeButton;
    private JButton downloadButton;

    public SimpleSkinViewer() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        imagebox = new JLabel("");
        imagebox.setIcon(new ImageIcon(loadImage("http://skins.minecraft.net/MinecraftSkins/AvarionDE.png")));

        loadButton = new JButton("Load Skin");
        changeButton = new JButton("Change Skin");
        downloadButton = new JButton("Download");

        //add listeners
        loadButton.addActionListener(this);
        changeButton.addActionListener(this);
        downloadButton.addActionListener(this);

        //dimensions
        imagebox.setMaximumSize(boxDimension);
        loadButton.setMaximumSize(buttonDimension);
        changeButton.setMaximumSize(buttonDimension);
        downloadButton.setMaximumSize(buttonDimension);

        add(imagebox);
        add(Box.createRigidArea(spaceDimension));
        add(loadButton);
        add(Box.createRigidArea(spaceDimension));
        add(changeButton);
        add(Box.createRigidArea(spaceDimension));
        add(downloadButton);
    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    }

    //and other stuff.....

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Avarion's Simple Skin Viewer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new SimpleSkinViewer());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting minimum and preferred size to the desired dimensions, and maximum size to Short.MAX_VALUE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs for BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

> When a BoxLayout lays out components from top to bottom, it tries to
>   size each component at the component's **preferred height**.
>
> For a top-to-bottom box layout, **the preferred width of the container
>   is that of the maximum preferred width of the children**. If the
>   container is forced to be wider than that, **BoxLayout attempts to size
>   the width of each component to that of the container's width (minus
>   insets)**. If the maximum size of a component is smaller than the width
>   of the container, then X alignment comes into play.

So, you can set both the `maximumSize` and `preferredSize` to get the desired size.

```
   loadButton.setMaximumSize(buttonDimension);
   loadButton.setPreferredSize(buttonDimension);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `Box.createVerticalGlue()`

Change

```
 add(changeButton);
 add(Box.createRigidArea(spaceDimension));
```

with

```
 add(changeButton);
 add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
```

Then you can use `.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x,y));` and buttons will adapt to your layout